# How to remove "Facebook Comments Plugin" link from facebook comment plugin

Tags: jquery, css, facebook

I'm trying to remove the link below in comment area (see attached) using jquery and css `display:none` style.

[image]

But i'm unable to remove that. Is it possible to remove that, then how to that. Looking for a help.

Comment: Do you have a working sample for this? We can't help with no code.

Comment: @PatrickMlr here what facebook provides https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#settings

Comment: The FB social plugins render inside an iframe, meaning you have no access to it with JS/CSS from your domain. Plus, changing how the social plugins look (apart from the configuration options they specifically offer for that purpose) is not even allowed.